# Subprocess.Popen but Sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, subprocess

What I'm trying to do is to create a Renderfarm, launching commands from weaker computers via Maya to the strong machine.
The problem is in the Server.py file, if I run with `subprocess.Popen(self.data)` then I can execute multiple commands without any issue, however, there is ZERO sequentiality here as the `Le_Print(self)` tester function is activated instantly after the args command is executed ... I don't want that as I need a subsequent function to move the rendered files from Desktop to the server location variable.

If I use `subprocees.run/call/check_call`, it works sequentially, BUT it is limited to one process for some reason I don't understand, AND it only works once, I can only make one ORDER and I have to restart the server.

TLDR: I need something like `subprocess.Popen(self.data, afterFunction= MyTransferFunction())`, or a way to make `subprocess.call` work on multithread AND be able to accept multiple commands at once.

Client:

```
ShotName = MayaRenderPath.split("/")[-3]
DesktopMayaRenderPath = HostName + "/MayaRenders/" + ShotName
print("HostDesktopMayaRenderPathName = {}".format(DesktopMayaRenderPath))

RoyalCommand = Constant + Constant2 + DesktopMayaRenderPath + " " + FullMayaPath
print("RoyalCommand = {}".format(RoyalCommand))

##########################################
#os.system(RoyalCommand)
HOST, PORT = "10.100.20.139", 9999
#data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
data = RoyalCommand
dmrp = DesktopMayaRenderPath
MayaPateshestvie = r"{}".format(MayaRenderPath)

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:

    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(bytes(data  , "utf-8"))
    sock.sendall(bytes("\n".join([dmrp,MayaPateshestvie]) , "utf-8"))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = str(sock.recv(2048), "utf-8")

print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
print("Received: {}".format(received))

##########################################
#def MyTransferFunction():
#for folder in os.listdir(DesktopMayaRenderPath):
#    shutil.move(DesktopMayaRenderPath + "/" + folder,MayaRenderPath)
#    shutil.move(os.path.join(DesktopMayaRenderPath,folder),MayaRenderPath)
#    try:
#        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(MayaRenderPath,folder),ignore_errors=True)
#        shutil.move(os.path.join(DesktopMayaRenderPath,folder),MayaRenderPath)
#    except: 
#        pass
```

Server:

```
from asyncio import constants
from asyncio.subprocess import STDOUT
from operator import sub
import socketserver
import os,subprocess
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """
    def Le_Printes(self):
        print("Le Finished")

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(2048).strip().decode('utf-8')
        self.dmrp, self.mrp = [i for i in self.request.recv(2048).decode('utf-8').split('\n')]
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print("RoyalCommand = {}".format(self.data))
        print("DesktopMayaRenderPath = {}".format(self.dmrp))
        print("MayaRenderPath = {}".format(self.mrp))

        self.HostName = os.path.expanduser("~")
        self.HostName = self.HostName.replace("\\","/") + "/Desktop"
        print("HostName = {}".format(self.HostName))

        subprocess.Popen(self.data)
        self.Le_Printes()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "10.100.20.139", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is non-blocking, while `subprocess.check_call` is, you should read the [`subprocess` library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). What data exactly do you need to send to send to the server, and what data do you need to retrieve after the job is finished ?

Comment: I solved this using Multithreading and subprocess.run. I needed just a few path-like variables, already done.